# how Deserializing this type of xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

```
<row>
    <id>1</id>
    <code></code>
    <name></name>
    <address></address>
    <state></state>
    <zone>?</zone>
</row>
<row>
    <id>2</id>
    <code>AA</code>
    <name>Ataria</name>
    <address>Sitapur National Highway 24, Uttar Pradesh</address>
    <state>Uttar Pradesh</state>
    <zone>NER</zone>
</row>
```

i have no root element in this xml file only row element start and end this xml file.
how Deserializing this type of data ? in c#

Answer (score 4):

If you sure that missing root is only the one issue with your XML - just add it manually:

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
string rawXml = "<root>" + fileContent + "</root>";

// now you can use LINQ-to-XML or whatever
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(rawXml);
```

Comment: Be careful with large files. So I like the answer of @Kevin Cathcart much more.

Comment: `File.ReadAllText` is not a point of an answer, point is creating root element manually

Comment: The question was to read this XML fragment and not how to add a root element ;-)

Comment: Right, in case of large file XmlReader would be better case but here is we have no such requirement and question is how to read xml since I've no root element

Answer (score 1):

You can also load an XML Fragment directly, via

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("tracelog.xml", settings))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Process each node of the fragment,
        // possibly using reader.ReadSubtree()
    }
}
```

You would create `XElement`s by passing the results of `reader.ReadSubTree()` to `XElement.Load(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well to start with, it's *not* an XML file - or at least, it doesn't represent an XML document.

One option would be to copy the file into a *new* file which *does* have document start/end tags... then you can load it as a normal document. Just create a file, write a document start tag, copy the contents of this file, then write a document end tag, and close the file handle. You could even do this in memory.

Alternatively, it *may* be possible to read it as it is, in fragments - possibly via `XmlReader`. I can't say it's something I've done, and I'd generally encourage you to create a full XML file instead, as then you'll be on more familiar territory.

Answer (score 0):

its not an XML file if it doesn't have the root. parser will throw an error if you try to parse it. you can do this way

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
--- add your file content here
</Root>
```

then give this file path to the  parser.